# QGIS - attribute(@atlas_feature) function in overlay filter

Tags: filter, select-by-attribute, overlay, atlas

I am actually trying to make a QGIS style that match my current entity in the atlas. For this, I need to use :

the functions `overlay_intersects` with one of my layer with filter the attribute value of my @atlas_feature. Problem is that the filter does not accept it.

For example, my `attribute(@atlas_feature, 'SECTION')` equals 1.

In my expression, if I use that: `overlay_intersects('CA',filter:=SECTION = (attribute(@atlas_feature,'SECTION')))` it doesn't work, but when I use the expression
`overlay_intersects('CA',filter:=SECTION = 1)`.

I tried to use the function `with_variable` but doesn't work too.
Am I doing something wrong or is the  combo attribute + @atlas_feature can't be used in filter ?

[image]
[image]